# assign white color with .at() not work

Tags: c++, opencv

i wrote this algorithm for a future erosion implementation. I'm testing the algorithm but i've got this problem:

when i try to color all pixel with white colour i get a image with column black and white, otherwise if i set each pixel black  it worked. how i can solve?

here's my code

```
Mat Morph_op_manager::erode_img(Mat image) {

//stucture element attribute

int strel_rows = 5;
int strel_cols = 5;

// center structure element attribute
int cr = 3;
int cc = 3;

//number of columns/rows after strel center
int nrac = strel_rows - cr ;
int ncac = strel_cols - cr ;


int min_val = 255;



for (int i = cr-1 ; i <image.rows-nrac ; i++) {
    for (int j = cc-1; j < image.cols-ncac ; j++) {

        for (int ii = 0; ii <strel_rows ; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj <strel_cols ; jj++) {

                image.at<int>(i-(nrac-ii),j-(ncac-jj)) = 255;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

i'm working with opencv in c++, file is a black and white image .tiff. here's my [output](http://tinypic.com/r/1twro4/9)

Comment: Not really the most optimal way to render a polar bear in a snow storm but still pretty impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you declared your `image` object but I bet it is of type `CV_8U`.

When you access the pixels you should write `image.at<uchar>((i-(nrac-ii),j-(ncac-jj))` instead of `image.at<int>((i-(nrac-ii),j-(ncac-jj))`. That's because you declared that the data in the matrix would be `uchar` (CV_8U) and not `int` (CV_32S).